# Can't get rewriterule substitution to work

Tags: htaccess, regular-expression

I am trying to use Apache rewrite to turn something like

```
https://www.example.com/sub/?v1=123&v2=456
```

into

```
https://www.example.com/sub/?v1=789&v2=456
```

i.e. changing v1 to a specific value and keeping v2.  In the real case, there are more parameters.

I have

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)v1=123&v2=(\d+).*$
RewriteRule ^sub/$ sub/?v1=789&v2=%1 [NE]
```

which does everything except keep v2. It gets:

```
 https://www.example.com/sub/?v1=789&v2=
```

It seems like the %1 substitution did not find anything to substitute.  But I can't see why not?

And I did try removing the [NE] flag, but that just causes the '&' to be lost, and does not keep the value either.

I tried this at https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and on our staging site, and its consistent that the substitution is not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)v1=123&v2=(\d+).*$
> RewriteRule ^sub/$ sub/?v1=789&v2=%1 [NE]
> ```

You are using the wrong backreference in the *substitution* string. You have 2 capturing subgroups in the preceding condition, so you would need to use `%2`, not `%1` as you have done. `%1` is a backreference to the first captured subgroup, ie. `(^|&)` - which "matches" `^` (start-of-string assertion) in your example URL and will therefore *appear* as an empty string in the substitution string.

However, instead of changing the backreference to `%2`, I would also consider changing the first subpattern (alternation group) to be non-capturing instead. ie. `(?:^|&)`. This would prevent a backreference being generated, so `%1` would indeed match `(\d+)`.

You don't appear to need the `NE` flag here (removing this should not "cause the '&' to be lost" in this context?). However, you may need the `L` flag to prevent further processing and potential conflicts with later directives.

The trailing `.*$` would seem to be unnecessary in the example you posted.

So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)v1=123&v2=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^sub/$ sub/?v1=789&v2=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

`%1` is the contents from the first set of parenthesis in your rewrite condition.  You have used TWO sets of parenthesis: `(^|&)` and `(\d+)`.  `%1` is matching the first of those which contains nothing but the  "start of the expression" (`^`), so no characters.

You have two possible solutions:

- Change your rewrite rule from using `%1` to using `%2`.
- Change your rewrite condition to use [non-capturing parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) for the first set:  `(?:^|&)`